# Hide title on <a> tag when hovered

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, lightbox2

I'm trying to hide the title tag when hovered ,or prevent its default action, I've research a lot of method on google. Yes they worked they hide the title but after hiding I cannot use the title caption. I want to Hide it and used it on the latter part of my code.

```
 <a  href=\"".$src."\" data-lightbox=\"example-3\" title=\"".$Tri_CAPTION."\">
```

Comment: instead of title change it to `data-title` or something else and use it

Comment: I'm using a minified jquery plugin, i cant edit the script

Comment: Thaks God, I fixed it, I did what you said even its hard to read the minified code.. Thanks

Comment: @user3196424 It sounds like you edited the code of your plugin script. That's generally bad practice, as it makes maintaining your fix irritating, difficult, and error-prone if you upgrade versions of the plugin and have to transfer it, or it causes unintended consequences/bugs in the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it inside a node for restoration or reference before removing like this:

```
$('a').data("title", $('a').attr("title")).removeAttr("title");

console.log($('a').data("title")); //retrieve the `data-title` which we're saving
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nwrHD/)

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the little `title` popup when hovering isn't something you can directly control, as it's browser/OS-level behavior.

You could *remove* the `title` attribute when hovering via JavaScript, which would provide nothing to display on hover and would presumably disable the hover popup altogether (it does on Chrome 31 for Win7 for me). You would then re-add the `title` when hovering stops. Example using jQuery's [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event listener function:

HTML

```
<a title="foobar">blarg</a>
```

JavaScript

```
var title; // Need to cache the title to add back when hovering stops

$('a').hover(function() {
    title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).attr('title', '');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('title', title);
});
```

Obviously you'd need to change the selector to which this applies for your own particular markup. I'm not sure how well this would play with your lightbox plugin, unfortunately, but adding it back in may make everything work together anyway.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug77Q/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do thta by using custom attribute and move title to that attribute;

```
<a href="#" title="lorem ipsum dolor" data-title="initial">Hover me</a>

$("a").hover(function() {
    $(this).prop("data-tite", $(this).attr("title"))
     $(this).removeAttr("title");
    console.log($(this).prop("data-tite"))
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5kF2/

Answer (score 0):

> write the css code like `display:none` for title attribute

```
a[title]{display:none;}
```

Comment: your selector targets all `a` elements with the `title` attribute, not the attribute itself. check what you suggest. -1 from me